# crop and get rest of the Image in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, crop, image-editing

I want to crop the image, and want to get the other portion of the image. Like the image as per below

[image]

and [image]

Here I want to create a transparent area of the selected portion of the image and make a new image.

I have also tried to get all the pixel and set alpha to 0 of select portion, but it didn't work.

Does anyone have any other solutions?

Here is the code I have used:

> ```
> CGSize size = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName].size;
> CGImageRef inImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName].CGImage;
> CFDataRef ref = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage));
> UInt8 * buf = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(ref);
> int length = CFDataGetLength(ref);
> float value2 =  (1 + value-0.5);
> NSLog(@"length  = %d",length);
> int row = 0,col = 0;
> for(int i=0; i<length; i+=4)
> {
>
>     int r = i;
>     int g = i+1;
>     int b = i+2;
>     int a = i+3;
>
>
>     col++;
>     if ((col % (int)size.width)==0 ) {
>         row++;
>         col=0;
>     }
>
>
>     int red = buf[r];
>     int green = buf[g];
>     int blue = buf[b];
>     int alpha = buf[a]; 
>
>
>     if (col > 25 && col < 75 && row > 25 && row < 75) {
>         alpha = 0;
>     }
>
>
>     buf[r] = SAFECOLOR(red);
>     buf[g] = SAFECOLOR(green);
>     buf[b] = SAFECOLOR(blue);
>     buf[a] = SAFECOLOR(alpha);
>
>
> }
> NSLog(@"CGImageGetAlphaInfo %d",CGImageGetAlphaInfo(inImage));
> NSLog(@"CGImageGetColorSpace %@",CGImageGetColorSpace(inImage));
>
> CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(buf,
>                                          CGImageGetWidth(inImage),
>                                          CGImageGetHeight(inImage),
>                                          CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(inImage),
>                                          CGImageGetBytesPerRow(inImage),
>                                          kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB,
>                                          kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
>
> CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
>
> imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it by painting transparent rectangle in `kCGBlendModeCopy` (which replaces destination pixels completely rather than blending with them)

```
UIImage* dst = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(dst.size);
[dst drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,dst.size.width,dst.size.height)];
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(25,25,50,50)] 
 fillWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy alpha:0];
UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The problem with your solution is probably in that in a bitmap with *premultiplied alpha* the R,G,B components are expected to be multiplied by A component, and that means if you set A to zero you must set R,G,B to zero too (as any value multiplied by A=0 will be zero).